# How does Cap know that Loki's punch packs a wallop?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

In the scene in *The Avengers* after Loki is captured, Cap and Stark are quietly wondering why the "Rock of ages" is giving up so easily. Cap says he recalls that that Loki packs a wallop. What is he referring to? When did Cap ever encounter Loki?

Comment: Er, didn't they briefly fight just before that? Right after the old man stood up and refused to bow down to Loki?

Comment: @Walt I think this question has been motivated by when Steve Rogers says "I don't remember it being that easy." at one point, a statement that sounds like he is saying he has fought Loki before now, and it was harder.

Comment: The scene I was referring to starts with Rogers saying to Stark "I don't like it". Stark Responds "What, the Rock of Ages Giving up so easily?" Leatherwing made a great point, and one that I hadn't considered. DrRDizzle, thanks for making the question clear. The "I don't remember it being that easy" remark is what baffled me. It led me to wonder where they fought before. If Rogers had just said "This guy was kicking my butt, thanks for saving me", I would have understood it better. Instead, I thought they had fought before

Comment: @DrRDizzle are you planning to add MCU tag to all questions manually ??

Comment: @Panther Yes - please see [this meta question](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1875/what-to-do-with-the-marvel-cinematic-universe) for details.

Comment: I believe if you ask some moderator they will go it by some script in single go. You can add comment in same question on Meta what is plan to implement same.

Answer (score 6):

Captain America is the [first one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uq88OfYENEk) to fight Loki in the Avengers movie. When Loki tries to subjugate the people by making them Kneel, Captain America comes to the calling first before Iron man shows up which leads to Loki surrendering easily.

Comment: I think this question has been motivated by when Steve Rogers says "I don't remember it being that easy." at one point, a statement that sounds like he is saying he has fought Loki before now, and it was harder.

Comment: @DrRDizzle It was easy for Iron Man, he just flew in and Loki surrendered. It was not easy for Captain America, who actually engaged in combat with Loki.So when Tony expressed concern that Loki surrendered easily, Cap was reminding him that it wasn't easy for everyone involved.

Comment: @Leatherwing That actually explains what I previously thought to be a very odd bit of dialouge in one of my favourite films. Thanks!